# JS Knockout - Enter key event binding on <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have some simple javascript which uses knockout that is intended to work as follows:

user can add comment, bringing up a textarea. Upon pressing enter, their comment is posted. They have a button to allow them to cancel the post and bring them back to add comment screen.

The problem is, when the user selects cancel (the `<a>` element below) while there is text in the textarea, my click event handler for the cancel is not called... until the second time it's clicked. However it will effectively cancel the post if the user has not typed anything yet in the textarea.

HTML:

```
<a data-bind="attr:{id:  $context.cellContext.status.rowIndex}, click: $parent.toggleCommentSelection" class="fa fa-plus" style="float: right"/>    
<textarea data-bind="attr:{id: 'commentField' + $context.cellContext.status.rowIndex}, event: { keyup: $parent.checkEntered,  }" class="comment-text-area" />
```

Javascript:

```
 self.toggleCommentSelection = function (data, event) {
        var targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
        self.currentRow(targetId);


        //stuff that gets called on cancel button click
        //if there is text in the text area this will not get called until 
        //clicked twice

    };

  self.checkEntered = function (data, event) {
        //stuff that gets called on keyup

        //enter key was pressed
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
               var comment = $.trim($('#commentField' + 
               self.currentRow()).val());
            if (comment.length > 0) {
                postComment(comment);
            } 
        }

    };
```

Any ideas on why my click binded function `toggleCommentSelection`is only called the second time it is clicked if there is text in the textarea?

Comment: For the beginning it looks like your html is wrong. There is no closing </a> tag so your <textarea> (also without closing tag BTW) goes inside the anchor.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it. I'm using /> instead of a full closing tag at the end of the elements. Thought it might affect functionality but it didn't after trying the other way.